# Apagar o primeiro numero se caso for 0

Tags: php

Como faço pra apagar o primeiro número se caso ele for igual a "0", por exemplo, tenho  o seguinte numero "0123" ficaria "123", se ele fosse "123" não aconteceria nada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [`ltrim`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ltrim.php), por padrão ele remove espaços no inicio do texto. Entretanto, especificando o último argumento, ele irá remover os caracteres especificados se aparecerem no inicio da string:

```
ltrim ('0123', '0');
```

Isto irá remover todos os `0` que sejam apresentados antes.

---

### Exemplos:

```
Original: 00000123
ltrim:    123

Original: 101
ltrim:    101

Original: 014410
ltrim:    14410

Original: 100
ltrim:    100

Original: 00100
ltrim:    100
```

[Teste isto](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fd5332f3c5055214a524c6825325d9f891093c82)

---

Caso o valor seja `0` ele irá também remover, ou seja `0`, `00` ou `00000` (...) se tornará *vazio*, uma alternativa, caso seja *int* é utilizar `(int)ltrim ($numero, '0')`

Comment: Usei e resolveu meu problema. Obrigado!